# How to determine if an argument in tcolorbox is empty?

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

I'm defining a tcolorbox environment with `xparse` library.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\DeclareTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}{g}
  {title={mybox \thetcbcounter}, IfValueT={#1}{label={mybox:#1}}}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{mybox}{}
  \ref{mybox:}
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{label}
  \ref{mybox:label}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want this box to have a label with a prefix `mybox:`. If I write

```latex
\begin{mybox}
  test
\end{mybox}
```

there won't be a label. However If I write

```latex
\begin{mybox}{}
  test
\end{mybox}
```

there will be a label named `mybox:` like the mwe above. If there are several environments like this, there will be a `Multiply-defined label` warning.

How can I make a blank argument `{}` works the same as no argument?

Comment: Optional arguments use square brackets.  A missing {} argument simply grabs whatever token is next (such as t from text).  Also, I could not find a {g} argument in xparse.

Comment: @JohnKormylo it's in sec 1.8 Backwards Compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `g` argument type: it's deprecated.

Just use a standard optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}{o}
  {
   title={mybox \thetcbcounter},
   IfValueT={#1}{label={mybox:#1}},
  }

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{mybox}
  test
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[label]
  \ref{mybox:label}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

You gain nothing from being able to code the first as

```
\begin{mybox}{}
  test
\end{mybox}
```

However, if you really insist, the code can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}{g}
  {
   title={mybox \thetcbcounter},
   IfValueT={#1}{mylabel=#1},
  }
\tcbset{
  mylabel/.code={
    \IfBlankTF{#1}{}{\tcbset{label={mybox:#1}}}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfBlankTF}{mmm}
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{mybox}{}
  test
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
  test
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{label}
  \ref{mybox:label}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file will have

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}test}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{mybox:label}{{1.3}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

so no label for the empty argument.

Anyway, the first approach is preferable. Really.

Note also `\NewTColorBox`, because `\DeclareTColorBox` would silently override an existing environment with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

`xparse` distinguishes the value of an optional argument when it's missing from when it's given an empty value, while `\newcommand` and its friends don't.

`\IfValueTF{<arg>}{<true>}{<false>}` checks if `<arg>` is missing (having value `-NoValue-` (`-`<sub>11</sub>`N`<sub>11</sub>`o`<sub>11</sub>`V`<sub>11</sub>`a`<sub>11</sub>`l`<sub>11</sub>`u`<sub>11</sub>`e`<sub>11</sub>`-`<sub>12</sub>, note the special catcode of the first `-`). `expl3`'s `\c_novalue_tl` and `\tl_if_novalue:nTF` play a similar role.

To check if an argument is empty, `\ifstrempty` from `etoolbox` fits the requirement. Since `tcolorbox` already loads `etoolbox`, there's no need to load it twice.

Imitating [how `tcolorbox` provides options `IfValue(TF)`](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/30887533aca45111340e6361fe3be5cef9421fc3/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbxparse.code.tex#L25-L34) as wrappers of `\IfValue(TF)`, here's an example to provide wrapper for `\ifstrempty` (with argument type `g` replaced with `o`):

```tex
% tcbxparse.code.tex
\tcbset{
  IfNoValueTF/.code n args={3}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}},
  IfNoValueT/.code n args={2}{\IfNoValueT{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
  IfNoValueF/.code n args={2}{\IfNoValueF{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
  IfValueTF/.code n args={3}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}},
  IfValueT/.code n args={2}{\IfValueT{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
  IfValueF/.code n args={2}{\IfValueF{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
}
```

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\tcbset{
  ifstrempty/.code n args={3}{\ifstrempty{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}},
}

\DeclareTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}{ o }
  {
    title={mybox \thetcbcounter},
    % add label only if #1 has value and is non empty
    IfNoValueTF={#1}{}{ifstrempty={#1}{}{label={mybox:#1}}}
  }

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{mybox}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[label]
\end{mybox}

\ref{mybox:}, \ref{mybox:label}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hmm the question title asks for "how to determine if ... is *blank*". Blank means either empty (`\mybox[]`) or space(s) only (`\mybox[ ]`). You can define a wrapper for `\ifblank` similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I mistook *blank* for *empty*,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I can define a new tcolorbox key to meet my demand.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\tcbset{
  mylabel/.code n args={1}
    {
      \def\temp{#1}
      \ifdefempty{\temp}{}{
        \tcbset{label={mybox:#1}}
        }
    }
}
\DeclareTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section]{mybox}{g}
  {title={mybox \thetcbcounter}, IfValueT={#1}{mylabel={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{mybox}{}
  test
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
  test
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}{label}
  \ref{mybox:label}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

I can do the empty judgment in the new key `mylabel`, and the problem is solved.